# what does babel-plugin-named-asset-import do

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Ok I've looked everywhere and there is no documentation on this Babel module
--babel-plugin-named-asset-import

can someone please explain what it is for and how it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like its purpose is to [import named exports](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3722) from non JS/CSS assets. Currently, within the CRA, it appears to only be implemented for [svg assets](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-single-bundle/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L400-L411). The goal is to offer another way to import SVGs as [React components](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs) versus the standard import as a `url` that needs to be applied to an `img` element.

***Without plugin*** (default import)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // import file as a url

function Header() {
  return <img src={logo} alt="logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

***With plugin*** (named import)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg'; // import file as a React component

function Header() {
  return <Logo />;
}

export default Header;
```

---

#### Update

Going deeper, it appears that the plugin aids in importing **svg** files in the following ways:

```
import logo from "logo.svg"; // default import
import { logoUrl } from "logo.svg"; // named import
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "@svgr/webpack?-svgo!logo.svg"; // ReactComponent import
```

The CRA specifically targets `svg` file formats as shown in their [test suites](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/babel-plugin-named-asset-import/index.test.js). As to whether or not it supports other non-js files, not likely (especially since the babel plugin is only utilized once in the CRA webpack config).

As mentioned in the svgr [docs](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/):

> SVGR can be used as a webpack loader, this way you can import your SVG directly as a React Component.

This particular plugin aims to import any `svg` file as **the default export**.

> Please note that by default, @svgr/webpack will try to export the React Component via default export if there is no other loader handling svg files with default export.

Whereas the CRA appears to utilize **file/url loader** for the default/named exports and specifically maps a [ReactComponent](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-single-bundle/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L406) named export to the svgr webpack plugin.

Comment: It seems that [@svgr/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) enables us to import .svg files with the format of react component. create-react-app's ejected configuration uses both babel-plugin-named-asset-import and @svgr/webpack. so what exactly babel-plugin-named-asset-import is doing currently?

Comment: Is babel-plugin-named-asset-import made on purpose of supporting all non-js files, on the other hand @svg/webpack only supports .svg files? so is babel-plugin-named-asset-import still in development stage?

Comment: Updated answer to include more in-depth details.